# Why does it so long for a Lithium-ion battery to be charged from 98% to 100%?

Tags: electrochemistry, electricity

Why does it so long for an Lithium-ion battery to be charged from 98% to 100%?

It is not even comparable to the effort I exerce to pump my bike tires from 95 psi to (the minimally usable) 100 psi. There the effort is a few times more than that needed to pump from 35 psi to 40 psi. With Apple's Lithium ion batteries, it takes at least an order of magnitude more to charge from 98-100% as it takes to charge from 8-10%.

Does the analogy hold? Is it actually chemically harder to charge? Is it detrimental to charge any faster (for heat, perhaps)? Is the internal charger simply delaying the charge to reduce the duration it will stay fully charged (because that itself is detrimental)?

The difference in rate-of-charging may be particularly noticeable this time because I was using a 20 W charger.

Comment: Well, in some sense, chemistry is involved in everything, from psychology to cosmology, but it does not mean chemists are experts for everything.

Comment: @Poutnik I'd have to dig out the reference, but chemists and other people who work in areas that are more inter-disciplinary tend to be better at understanding more things.

Comment: @Zhe I do not disagree, but people not involved in chemistry often stretch this assumed knowledge a lot, taking chemists almost as magicians who control the mystery of knowledge of everything. :-)

Comment: What does it mean (to Apple engineers) that the battery is 98% charged? How do they measure it?

Comment: @KarstenTheis The output voltage probably correlates well with the amount of charging.

Comment: @KarstenTheis These devices usually implement hardware charge counters, based on current integration. This charge is compared to the nominal or actually measured capacity.

Comment: @Zhe Dependence voltage versus charge is highly nonlinear and depends on the way of cell usage and age.

Comment: @Poutnik Yeah, I'm guessing even sampling the voltage is not an easy thing to do. I didn't know about charge counters, so thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Zhe I must correct myself here. Phones do have current sensors, but the passed charge is , at least at some devices, counted by a software way by current sampling. Unfortunately for charge management, Android devices seems to derive charge percentage from the voltage, so the percentage scale is nonlinear, dropping much faster near 0%, compared to near 100%.  I have no  personal experience with iPhones nor other Apple devices.

Comment: It could be more chemistry oriented if we assume that 98 and 100 refer indeed to the amount of charge actually stored in a Li ions battery.

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is: The ending stage uses much smaller charging current, so it lasts longer. TCharging of any cell in the contant voltage mode, not limited to lithium cells, leads to asymptotically decreasing of the charging current and progressively slowing down charging proces.

The reason behind is the charging voltage must not cross the maximal allowed voltage to avoid detrimental or even dangerous side chemical processes. These processes  may include :

- forming metallic lithium on surface of graphite-lithium intercalate $\ce{C6Li_x}$
- reaction of lithium with the dialkylcarbonate solvent
- irreversible collapse of $\ce{Li_xCoO2}$ structure, forming $\ce{CoO2}$ and $\ce{Li2O}$, if too many of lithium ions leave the compound.
- forming gases from side reactions, like alkanes and ethers.
- a rupture of the cell
- ignition of the volatile flammable solvent, powered by metallic lithium.

---

This observed slow end of charging phenomena is not iPhone specific, but applies to all devices using Li-ion/Li-Po cell technology. It is matter of the lithium cell protection-circuit design and the device charging control software/firmware design.

The usual Li-ion/Li-Po charging schema is

1. Optional Trickle charge ( the link terminology ) by  low current to revive deeply  discharged cell.
2. Charging by a constant current until the battery maximal voltage threshold is reached. This happens typically when 70-80% of the actual cell capacity is reached, the lower value for older cells with greater internal resistancy.
3. Charging switches to the constant voltage charging, with the charging current asymptotically decreasing toward zero. Charging is then usually stopped when the currect drops below the chosen minimal charging current threshold. This mode provide lower charge increase per time, as the average current is lower.
4. Some charging algorithms use as the last  step the "topping" charging mode of staying at the maximal voltage for some time, to push into the cell the maximal charge ever possible, with expense of the cell life-time. This topping significantly prolongs the total charging time, as the average charging current is minimal here.

I have answered from my memory,but there is plenty of related online resources, like e.g. [powerelectronics - charging-liion-batteries-for-maximum-run-times](https://www.powerelectronics.com/content/article/21855733/charging-liion-batteries-for-maximum-run-times)

Comment: That all makes sense, but what is your level of confidence in your answer? When you write "_chemistry is involved in everything, from psychology to cosmology, but it does not mean chemists are experts for everything._", I get the impression that you're taking a stab at the answer, but are not really sure. Can you clarify either way?

Comment: @Sam I have not fully got your last sentence before the ending question. I have not answered from the chemistry point of view, as chemistry has little to do with that ( It has, but indirectly, via the critical cell maximum voltage). I have answered from point of view of many years of experience in lithium cell maintenance. All chargers charge them asymptotically, so it is clear that the ending amount of charge takes a lot longer than the same but starting amount of charge. –

Comment: By other words, I am quite confident in that, what is based on quite a lot of reading and experience. I think if you searched about the topic little bit before asking, you would reach the similar conclusion and would not even ask. It is quite widely spread public knowledge about CC/CV charging of lithium cells.

Comment: If the question is junk, let's not sully the site with noise. Please delete your answer, so that I can delete my question. Thanks.

Comment: No need to delete, there are much worse questions here.

Comment: @Sam you should be aware that the answerer had invested time and effort into answering your question and you shouldn't tell him to delete the answer(which means all the time and effort will go to waste). Everyone is welcome to contribute here and your question though closed will be helpful for future readers (only difference is that you will not get further answers) and as Poutnik said, there are much worse questions. If you got your answer, please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign or edit your question to clarify your doubt.

Comment: @NilayGhosh AFAIK there is another difference that only the author, moderators and senior users with closing/reopen vote privilege can see a closed question. Try to log out and find the question.